# Structured binding reference with tuple of reference

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

The [Structured binding Case2 in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) is a bit hard to understand. Basically, I want a clarification of these situations

```cpp
int x = 1;
double y = 2.0;
auto [a, b] = std::forward_as_tuple(x, y);   //a, b are both reference, why?
auto&& [c, d] = std::forward_as_tuple(x, y); //What's the difference of this and above?
auto&& [e, f] = std::tuple{x, y};  //why are NOT e, f rvalue references? Resharper shows them as value type not reference type
```

And if there is some function return tuple of reference, how can I make a copy using structured binding?

```cpp
std::tuple<int&, double&> f;
auto [x, y] = f(); //But I want a copy from the reference, how?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::forward_as_tuple(x, y)` gives you a `tuple<int&, double&>`. The types of the bindings into that are `int&` and `double&` (in the same way that the types of the bindings into `tuple<int, double>` are `int` and `double`). Basically:

```cpp
auto [a, b] = std::forward_as_tuple(x, y);
auto&& [c, d] = std::forward_as_tuple(x, y);
```

behaves as if:

```cpp
auto __e = std::forward_as_tuple(x, y);
using __E = remove_reference_t<decltype(__e)>;
tuple_element_t<0, __E>&& a = std::get<0>(std::move(__e));
tuple_element_t<1, __E>&& b = std::get<1>(std::move(__e));

auto&& __f = std::forward_as_tuple(x, y);
using __F = remove_reference_t<decltype(__f)>;
tuple_element_t<0, F>&& c = std::get<0>(std::move(__f));
tuple_element_t<1, F>&& d = std::get<1>(std::move(__f));
```

So `a` is an rvalue reference to `int&` and `c` is an rvalue reference to `double&`, so `int&` and `double&` respectively. This particular formulation (I'm specifically calling it a reference to reference, rather than calling it just `int&`) is necessary because `decltype(name)` where `name` is a structured binding gives you the *referenced* type, which is why `decltype(a)` would give you `int&`.

The above also shows the difference between the `[a, b]` and the `[c, d]` case: the `auto` vs `auto&&` declaration applies to the unnamed object that we're destructuring. It does not affect the bindings themselves<sup>†</sup>.

This case:

```cpp
auto&& [e, f] = std::tuple{x, y};
```

Does not give references because it unpacks to:

```cpp
auto&& __g = std::tuple{x, y};
using __G = remove_reference_t<decltype(__g)>;
tuple_element_t<0, G>&& e = std::get<0>(std::move(__g));
tuple_element_t<1, G>&& f = std::get<1>(std::move(__g));
```

So `e` is an rvalue reference to `int`, which means `decltype(e)` is `int`, not `int&`.

---

> And if there is some function return tuple of reference, how can I make a copy using structured binding?

You can't make a copy using structured bindings. Structured bindings is *solely* about destructuring an object, it is not at all about changing anything. If you want to make a copy, you have to do that manually:

```cpp
std::tuple<int&, double&> f = /* ... */;
std::tuple<int, double> actual_copy = f;
auto& [x, y] = actual_copy;
```

<sup>†</sup>In the above case, because the underlying object being destructured is an lvalue reference (`auto&`), this technically makes the bindings themselves lvalue references to whatever instead of rvalue references to whatever -- although I'm not sure if this is actually a meaningful distinction.

Comment: Why does ``auto&& [e, f] = std::tuple{x, y};`` unpacks to ``auto&& __g = std::forward_as_tuple(x, y);`` ? And why ``tuple_element_t<0, decltype(__g)>&& e`` evaluate to ``int`` but not ``int&&`` ?

Comment: @szppeter First one is a typo sorry. `tuple_element_t<0, decltype(__g)>` is `int`. The actual _type_ of `e` is `int&&`, but that's not what `decltype(e)` gives you - it gives you the referenced type, and the referenced type of `int&&` is `int`.

Comment: ``tuple_element_t<0, decltype(__g)>&&`` doesn't compile in the ``std::tuple{x, y}`` case

Comment: @szppeter Yeah that was just missing a `remove_reference_t`.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is some function return tuple of reference, how can I make a copy using structured binding?

Perhaps a helper function such as following would be useful:

```
template <class Tuple, size_t... indices>
constexpr auto
tuple_copy_impl(const Tuple& tuple, std::index_sequence<indices...>) {
   return std::tuple{std::get<indices>(tuple)...};
}

template <class Tuple>
constexpr auto
tuple_copy(const Tuple& tuple) {
    constexpr auto s = std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>;
    using I = std::make_index_sequence<s>;
    return tuple_copy_impl<Tuple>(tuple, I{});
}

auto [x, y] = tuple_copy(f());
```